# Deploying (and hosting) a LangChain code on StreamLit throws PydanticUserError

Tags: streamlit, pydantic, openai-api, langchain, nlp-question-answering

I built a pdf document question-answering using LangChain, OpenAI (embeddings and LLM) and Chroma (for storing the vector embeddings) and UI with StreamLit. I am trying to deploy and host the webapp using StreamLit cloud services. And on installing all the required libraries and packages, the webapp throws an error:

```
PydanticUserError: If you use `@root_validator` with pre=False (the default) you MUST specify `skip_on_failure=True`. Note that `@root_validator` is deprecated and should be replaced with `@model_validator`. For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.0.2/u/root-validator-pre-skip
```

followed by a Traceback:

```
Traceback:
    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/opt/render/project/src/app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from langchain.document_loaders import PyMuPDFLoader, PyPDFLoader
File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/langchain/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from langchain.agents import MRKLChain, ReActChain, SelfAskWithSearchChain
File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/langchain/agents/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from langchain.agents.agent import Agent
File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 10, in <module>
    from langchain.chains.base import Chain
File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/langchain/chains/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from langchain.chains.conversation.base import ConversationChain
File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/langchain/chains/conversation/base.py", line 7, in <module>
    from langchain.chains.conversation.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/langchain/chains/conversation/memory.py", line 7, in <module>
    from langchain.chains.conversation.prompt import SUMMARY_PROMPT
File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/langchain/chains/conversation/prompt.py", line 2, in <module>
    from langchain.prompts.prompt import PromptTemplate
File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/langchain/prompts/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from langchain.prompts.base import BasePromptTemplate
File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/langchain/prompts/base.py", line 35, in <module>
    class BasePromptTemplate(BaseModel, ABC):
File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/langchain/prompts/base.py", line 41, in BasePromptTemplate
    @root_validator()
File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydantic/deprecated/class_validators.py", line 231, in root_validator
    code='root-validator-pre-skip',
```

How to deal with this error, although I believe I have installed all the necessary packages with compatible versions?

I am trying to see the url that the error shows but could not find anything good enough to debug the error.

Comment: share the github repository

Comment: This thread has some ideas I am trying: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76614379/roo-validator-error-when-importing-langchain-text-splitter-python

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pip install ydata-profiling
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been reading this thread and trying different versions of langchain an pydantic.  Still failing with Pydantic 1.10.9 and Langchain 0.0.231.

[@roo_validator error when importing langchain.text_splitter Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76614379/roo-validator-error-when-importing-langchain-text-splitter-python)