# PydanticUserError with @root_validator in langchain package

Tags: python-3.x, langchain

I'm following the tutorial on SQL Database on python.langchain.com... https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/toolkits/sql_database

Python 3.8.0

I'm working with the langchain package in Python and encountered an error related to pydantic's @root_validator. I believe it's a compatibility issue between the two, but I'm unsure how to proceed. I've pasted my code and the error message below. Any help or insights would be appreciated!

```
from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import SQLDatabaseToolkit
from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase
from langchain.llms.openai import OpenAI
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor
from langchain.agents.agent_types import AgentType
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

db = SQLDatabase.from_uri("sqlite:Chinook.db")
toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=db, llm=OpenAI(temperature=0))

agent_executor = create_sql_agent(
    llm=OpenAI(temperature=0),
    toolkit=toolkit,
    verbose=True,
    agent_type=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
)

agent_executor.run("Describe the playlisttrack table")
```

Error:

```
PS D:\utils> python chatgpt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chatgpt.py", line 1, in <module>
    from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from langchain.agents import MRKLChain, ReActChain, SelfAskWithSearchChain
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from langchain.agents.agent import Agent
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 10, in <module>
    from langchain.chains.base import Chain
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from langchain.chains.conversation.base import ConversationChain
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\conversation\base.py", line 7, in <module>
    from langchain.chains.conversation.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\conversation\memory.py", line 7, in <module>
    from langchain.chains.conversation.prompt import SUMMARY_PROMPT
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\conversation\prompt.py", line 2, in <module>
    from langchain.prompts.prompt import PromptTemplate
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\prompts\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from langchain.prompts.base import BasePromptTemplate
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\prompts\base.py", line 35, in <module>
    class BasePromptTemplate(BaseModel, ABC):
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\prompts\base.py", line 41, in BasePromptTemplate
    @root_validator()
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydantic\deprecated\class_validators.py", line 228, in root_validator
    raise PydanticUserError(
pydantic.errors.PydanticUserError: If you use `@root_validator` with pre=False (the default) you MUST specify `skip_on_failure=True`. Note that `@root_validator` is deprecated and should be replaced with `@model_validator`.

For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/u/root-validator-pre-skip
```

Comment: What version of langchain and pydantic do you have installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploying (and hosting) a LangChain code on StreamLit throws PydanticUserError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76651314/deploying-and-hosting-a-langchain-code-on-streamlit-throws-pydanticusererror)

Comment: @ewokx langchain 0.0.27, pydantic 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can try upgrading python first and check if issue persist. Most probably upgrading pyhton should resolve you problem

Second check in you environment

```
pip list | grep pydantic
pydantic  #version ?.?.?
```

You can downgrade your pydantic to appropriate version (based on your requirement)

Comment: how do I know the appropriate version? Per the documentation I have followed none is specified.

Comment: latest stable version is always preferred..